# What statistics to use for testing hypothesis about regression coefficient when n is greater than 30

Tags: regression, time-series

What statistics to use for testing hypothesis about regression coefficient when n is 120.
 I plan using a z score but am not sure.

Comment: Is this regression or time-series (you have the time series tag)?

Comment: Do you really mean time series? If it is just a regression, you plan to use a z-score of what quantity, and do what with it? Do you mean 'I plan to take the usual t-statistic for a coefficient (estimate/s.e.) and use a z-test with it'? If so, n=120 should be fine. I wouldn't do it at n=30, but YMMV.

Comment: i fitted a linear mathematical trend to a time series data and i want to test for the significance of the regression coefficient.

Comment: @uchembaka Such regression on time variable is feasible only if justified by the theory of the underlying process (even more so as for higher degree polynomial regression). Otherwise such series should be viewed as random walk with a drift and processed by the respective ARIMA model.

Comment: @ Glen_b What is YMMV?

Comment: [Your mileage may vary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=YMMV).